# Apps Script on site stopped working

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sites

OS: windows 7

Browser: Firefox and Chrome

I have a few pages on my google site that use google apps script to collect data from a spreadsheet and display them on the page as part of the Google Apps Scripts Gadget. Recently, (within the last few days), the **information that it is supposed to display from the spreadsheet is not showing up**. It's just blank. The rest of the script seems to run fine, but it's difficult to tell.

I haven't changed any of the code since the last working version (I've been using this setup and code for around 2 months and it worked almost perfectly before). I debugged the functions that get the data and they are still working fine, and the data is in the same format as it was previously.

Here's the code I've been using if that helps. Site traffic is around 200 visits per month if that matters.

```
  function doGet() {
    var t=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Practices');
    return t.evaluate();
  }


  function getData() {
    var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById('CORRECT SPREADSHEET KEY').getSheetByName('Practices');
    return sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
}
```

And this is the block of code in the Practices.html file that I believe is not working. (none of this data is showing up, but the rest of it is)

```
<div class="carousel" style="display:none;">
  <div class="items">
    <? var date= new Date(); ?>
    <? var data = getData();
     for (var i = 1; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>


      <div>
        <h3><?= data[i][0] ?></h3>
        <p>Date: <?=data[i][1].getMonth()+1 ?>/<?=data[i][1].getDate()?>/<?=data[i][1].getFullYear() ?></p>
        <p><?= data[i][2] ?> </p>
      </div>
    <? } ?>


  </div>
  </div>
```

I am aware there is a display:none; in this code. It is switched to show later. For some reason if the display:none; is not there it only displays the first slide, but none of the slides after it.

UPDATE: Inspected the html of the page and all the data is there, with the proper tags and structure. This led me to think it was the jquery scripts I use to animate and change the display setting. I created another page with the same jquery functions, but without having to get data from the spreadsheet and it worked fine. Although, this was not through the apps script gadget.

Comment: Is there any difference if you run the app as standalone web app instead of a site gadget? I'm also skeptical of this chunk of code - data[i][1].getMonth()+1. How are you able to call getMonth() on an array of data directly from the spreadsheet? Are there date objects in there?

Comment: Well Arun, the date objects should be there. Range.getValues have always returned parsed values of the cells, e.g. strings, numbers, booleans *and* dates. It's just **the oldest** API on Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample spreadsheet and a script with your exact code, minus the display:none style you mentioned isn't your problem. And it did work perfectly. Which indicates that your issue is somewhere else.

Here is the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhfBwM8xuKeSdElFSXpIWllKekRyc0EwdF9uZ0VLanc

And here is the script:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwH9zKHFLQ2u_I21xLkG8xgrr_F_Ir_oioE8mOuW4H7kc8WEnVs/exec

Have you tried inspecting your page using Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox's, etc, to see if the structure is there?
You might also want to take a look at your page's code before evaluated by calling a `t.getCode()` as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#DebuggingTemplates).

**edit**

If you're using jQuery with your HtmlService, it might be the issue. A recent release of Apps Script (no release notes) have broke a lot of jQuery's features (along with other things) but there's no error messages, it just silently don't work. It's so buggy now that I've given up on using jQuery with Apps Script. All new apps I built used plain javascript now as it's way easier to pinpoint (and workaround) the buggy methods.

Comment: I know the code works. Its been working for over 2 months. I'm just trying to figure out why it suddenly stopped on multiple browsers at the same time. I tried the t.getcode() and it looked find. I also tried inspecting the page with firefox, but I'm not really sure what's going on with that or what I should be looking for.

Comment: Update: I used the inspection element to look at the html, everything that should be there is in terms of structure. It may be the jquery code that's causing issues. (The one that's supposed to switch the items from display none to show, etc. )

Comment: So you're using jQuery? That probably the issue, I've updated my answer with new info.